# Regular Expression gives wrong matches in QRegEx

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I have the following function which should give me the matched string from a regular expression:

```
QString selectByPattern(QString const &oValue, QString const &oPattern, bool bRegularExpression) const
{
    QString s;
    QRegExp regex;

    // default
    regex.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::RegExp);

    regex.setPattern(oPattern);
    int i = oValue.indexOf(regex);
    int l = regex.matchedLength();

    if(i == -1 || l < 1)
        return s;

    s = oValue.mid(i, l);

    return s;
}
```

I'm using the string `*VALUE*` as  input for testing this. Now i get the following results:

```
 oPattern = "[A-Z]"
 Output = "V"
```

which is correct. For this pattern it gives me the first upper case character and a length of 1.

But when I use this:

```
 oPattern = "[A-Z]*"
 Output = ""
```

and I don't understand why. The index returned is `0` and length is also `0`. First of all, of course the index is wrong, because it should be `1`. And then I don't understand the meaning of `0` as length. According to the documentation (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#pattern) Either there is a match, then the index is a positive value, and in that case I would expect that `matchedLength()` should also return some value `> 0``.

Am I missunderstanding something here, or is this a problem in Qt 5.2.1?

Comment: Strange. That works correct, but according to the docs, and to my knowledge of regex (which is rather limited), this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[A-Z]*
```

can matched the string `VALUE` and an empty string as well. [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/60). The second match will be of `0` length as after `VALUE` is matched nothing is left.

You can try `[A-Z]+`

Your index is 0, because positions in strings start with 0.

```
string:   "VALUE"
           ^   ^
position:  0   4
```

So the match (`pos=0`, `len=3`) would be the following `VAL`, (`pos=0`, `len=1`) is `V` and (`pos=0`, `len=0`) is the empty string.

Comment: While it works with the `+` it doesn't really explain why it doesn't work with `*`even though it should.

Comment: @Devolus your match will give two results.`VALUE` and ``.So the second one might be overwriting the first one.

Comment: Hmmm. that could be true. I have to test this. But I would have expected that the result of `indexOf` gives me the first occurence, otherwise the interface doesn't really make sense IMO.

Comment: @Devolus index might also be getting overwritten.Index should have been `5` though.With `[A-Z]+` all results are correct right?

Comment: @Devolus you might want to review the extended answer for deeper understanding.

Comment: @SimonWarta it will match 2 strings.`VALUE` and then the empty string ``.See debugger at regex101.com

Comment: @vks you are right, only the "ungreedy" mode in PCRE results in multiple sub-matches: http://regex101.com/r/yM3nC0/1

Comment: The inputvalue is `*VALUE*` so the match would be at 1. I know that poisitions in strings in C++ are usually zero based. ;) That's why I was wondering why the returncode from the QT library is 0, but only in the case using '*'. Reading the documentation, I still think this is a bug, because it should report the FIRST match, even iftherre are multiple occurences. Otherwise the interface doesn't make sense, or I should use the function returning a list of all matches. Which also didn't work because it gave me ONLY the empty string as result instead of two, which you are telling me it would.